# Deployment error "Too many automatic redirections were attempted" in Sharepoint Add In App

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, sharepoint-2013, provider-hosted

I'm working on the Provider-hosted app with Sharepoint 2013 on Premises.
I have created the Sharepoint Add-In app in Visual Studio 2017.
After that, once I build the solution and run the solution at that time I'm getting an error as

> Too many automatic redirections were attempted" Deployment error.

I have followed the steps for creating a Provided hosted app in http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-approach-to-create-a-Provider-Hosted-Application-in-SharePoint-2013
Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Anyone please me on this issues.........